# Sending POST request to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, api, post

I have a problem with sending POST request to ASP.NET Web API.
Here is my code, I'd appreciate if anyone could help:

**WebAPiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
        );


    }
}
```

**Affiliate Controller.cs**

```
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Address address)
    {
        //code

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
var address = {
    adr_id: $('#iadr_id').val(),
    adr_street_name: $('#iadr_street_name').val(),
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(address),
    url: "api/affiliate",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I get this:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I suggest to first try out the Api call in Fiddler or similar; at least you know if the problem is on the client side or the server.

Comment: I fixed it! I added this code to WebApiConfig.cs:

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "PostApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Post"
            );

Thanks all for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
I added this code to WebApiConfig.cs:

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "PostApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Post"
            );

Thanks all for your time and consideration.